# Ext js autoDestroy on Store

Tags: extjs, store, destroy

I have a Store connected to a grid an configured `autoDestroy` as `true`. Will the store be destroyed when the grid is destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's what it says in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-autoDestroy).